# How to dynamically create horizontally scrolling listbox of images in Windows phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, horizontal-scrolling

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstbox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

I am able to create horizontally scrolling list of images via this design time code.
Right now i am able to add images at runtime,
**But i am not able to produce same effect via code in runtime....**

Comment: Why do you need to do this with code instead of directly in XAML?

Comment: please add more content.

Comment: @Cybermaxs "No tags in title" refers to titles like "[Windows Phone 7]How to dynamically …" There's nothing wrong with a title like "How to … in Windows Phone 7", that's a well-formed English sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to go:

```
        string xaml =
        "<ListBox x:Name='lstbox' ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility='Disabled' ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility='Visible'>"+
        "<ListBox.ItemsPanel>"+
            "<ItemsPanelTemplate>"+
                "<StackPanel Orientation='Horizontal' />"+
            "</ItemsPanelTemplate>"+
        "</ListBox.ItemsPanel>";

UIElement tree = (UIElement)XamlReader.Load(xaml);

LayoutRoot.Children.Add(tree);
```

Comment: thanks so much for the solution, it worked for me.....but i can't vote it becz it need 15 reputation and right now i don't have..